# PHP inheritance: how to access child property from inherited parent's method?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

For example:

```
<?php 

class animal {  
  private $property = "animal";
  public function whoami() {
    return "I am an " . $this->property . ".\n";
  }
}

class emu extends animal {
  private $property = "emu";
}

$emu = new emu;
echo $emu->whoami(); // "I am an animal"
```

The above code will report "I am an animal", but I would like it to report "I am an emu", without needing to override the whoami() method.

Is there any way of doing this in PHP?

Comment: `private` properties can only be accessed by the class that defines the property. I think `protected` is what you are after here. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you @cOle2 - and a public property works too, but then it's public of course.

Comment: A general rule of thumb when dealing with inheritance: if both the parent and the child class have a private property or method of the same name, then it should *not* be private. It should be protected.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @cOle2 in a comment above:

> private properties can only be accessed by the class that defines the property. I think protected is what you are after here. See [php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can create getters and setters to access and Modify the attribute. One solution would be this:

```
 class animal {  
  private $property;

  public function getAnimal() {
      return $this->property;
  }

  public function setAnimal($animal) {
    $this->property = $animal;
  }

  public function whoami() {
    return "I am an " . $this->getAnimal() . ".\n";
  }
}

class emu extends animal {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::setAnimal("Emu");
    }
}

$emu = new emu();
echo $emu->whoami();
```